# Best way to store/retrieve big array (mixture of string and typed array) into/from blob or file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typed-arrays

Lets say I have big array which has different type of data like **json string** and **typed array** such as `mainData`

```
var strObj = JSON.stringify({'name' : 'suman', 'age' : 29};);
var strObj2 = JSON.stringify({'name' : 'laxmi', 'age' : 29});

var tpArr = new Uint8Array(2);
    tpArr[0]  = 42;
    tpArr[1]  = 52;

var tpArr2 = new Uint8Array(2);
    tpArr[0]  = 32;
    tpArr[1]  = 52;

var mainData = [{pt : 20, recObjs : strObj}, {pt : 30, recObjs : strObj2},
                {pt : 40, recObjs : tpArr}, {pt : 50, recObjs : tpArr2}];
```

I have created blob file(type json) with array `mainData` and export it into json file, like

```
var stringiFyData = JSON.stringify(mainData);   
var myBlob = new Blob([stringiFyData], {'type': 'application/json'});
var link2 = document.getElementById('mydata');
link2.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
```

Now after file exported as json, I read the file something like,

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
     mainData = JSON.parse(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Now elements of `mainData` array,  `tpArr`, `tpArr2` lost their's original type from **Uint8Array** into **Object**.

I need this data `tpArr`, `tpArr2` in it's original form. For this, first I do convert `tpArr` object into array. After get the length of array,  create typed array something like

```
newTypeArr = new Uint8Array(conNewArr.length);
for(var i=0; i<conNewArr.length; i++ ){
    newTypeArr[i] = conNewArr[i];
}
```

But length of `conNewArr` array is about 3000 and which means we have to run loop 6000, first 3000 to convert object into array to know the length, and second 3000 to a create typed array.

And of course the `mainData` may has that kind of array in thousands.

**Other alternative**

I tried to export(`new Blob(mainData, {'type': 'application/octet-stream'}`) it into array buffer and after read the exported file, I got all the data in typed array format but I need these data as it was before exported(mixture of string and typed array).

**My questions are**

1. How can we export mixtutre data of string and typed array in blob file and retrieve these data from blob/file without loosing it's  original form(type)?
2. Is the my approach okay ?
3. How can we reduce the iteration of such big loop in my approach?

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 var myObject = {'name' : 'suman', 'age' : 29};
 var myObject2 = {'name' : 'laxmi', 'age' : 29};
 
 var strObj = JSON.stringify(myObject);
 var strObj2 = JSON.stringify(myObject2);
 
 var tpArr = new Uint8Array(5);
  tpArr[0]  = 42;
  tpArr[1]  = 52;
  tpArr[2]  = 62;
  tpArr[3]  = 22;
  tpArr[4]  = 42;
     
 var tpArr2 = new Uint8Array(5);
  tpArr[0]  = 32;
  tpArr[1]  = 52;
  tpArr[2]  = 42;
  tpArr[3]  = 402;
  tpArr[4]  = 142;

 var mainData = [
  {pt : 20, recObjs : strObj},
  {pt : 30, recObjs : strObj2},
  {pt : 40, recObjs : tpArr},
  {pt : 50, recObjs : tpArr2}
  ];
 
 
 var stringiFyData = JSON.stringify(mainData); 
 var myBlob = new Blob([stringiFyData], {'type': 'application/json'});
 var link2 = document.getElementById('mydata');
 link2.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
 
 function readFile (){
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    data = JSON.parse(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file); 
 }
```

```html
<a href="#"  id="mydata" >Download Data</a>
 <input type='file' id="fileInput" accept='text/plain' onchange='readFile()'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to export everything is Blob?
Maybe you want to export all data as single file and import it again at later stage.

I suggest following.

Convert all Typed array into Base64 and JSON at end.

https://jsfiddle.net/esusedf7/2/

```
// Create a array with dummy Values
var typed_array = new Uint8Array(100000);
for (var i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    typed_array[i]=i;
}

// Convert Array into Base64
var sMyBase64 = base64EncArr(typed_array);
// Convert Base64 to Array
var ori1 = base64DecToArr(sMyBase64);

// Convert Array into String (comma seperated)
var comma = bufferToString(typed_array);
// Convert String (comma seperated) into Array
var ori2 = stringToBuffer(comma);

// Compare if converted array is exactly equal to Original Array
if (typed_array.length == ori2.length) {
    var match=0;
    for (var i=0;i<2000;i++) {
        if (typed_array[i] !== ori2[i]) {
            match = 1;
        }
    }
    if (match == 1) {
        alert('ori2 Fail');
    }
} else {
    alert('ori2 Fail');
}
```

Original Array: 100000
Base64 String: 136844 Percentage Increase 137%
Comma String: 356989 Percentage Increase 357%
Json String: 1145881 Percentage Increase 1146%